# postgres tablefunc module using hql hibernate queries?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, crosstab

Would you know how to use the postgres crosstab (tablefunc) function in a HQL query? Do you need to register the function with Hibernate?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
unexpected token: CROSSTAB near line 1, column 34 [SELECT * from CROSSTAB('select ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in HQL, since HQL is a different language which is independent of database implementations. If you want to use features specific to PostgreSQL (such as crosstab) you will need the [native query interface](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html).